# How do I extract an imageset from srcset attribute?

Tags: regex, html, image, set

Using the official spec for the HTML5 srcset [image candidate string](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#image-candidate-string), I've created the following regex:

```
/<img[^\>]*[^\>\S]+srcset=['"](?:([^"'\s,]+)\s*(?:\s+\d+[wx])(?:,\s*)?)+["']/gm
```

...Which should match the following tag:

```
<img srcset="image@2x.png 2x, image@4x.png 4x, image@6x.png 6x">
```

...And return the three filenames specified (`image@2x.png`, `image@4x.png`, `image@6x.png`).

However, even though it matches, it's only returning the last one. See this [Regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kI6yL7/7).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use html parsers?

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's part of a pull request I'm doing to `grunt-imagemin`, which (alas) uses regex. Insert link to that classic "WTF are you parsing HTML with regex?!" answer here...

Comment: Obligatory self-link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see in this visualization, the capture-group parenthesis are inside a repeated pattern. This causes the regex to only return the last one.

```
<img[^\>]*[^\>\S]+srcset=['"](?:([^"'\s,]+)\s*(?:\s+\d+[wx])(?:,\s*)?)+["']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/E-fzWzUKjazAsagL)

Regexes **can't** return *multiple* instances of the *same* capture group. What you need to do is capture the entire thing and then examine it further to get the individual filenames:

```
<img[^\>]*[^\>\S]+srcset=['"]((?:[^"'\s,]+\s*(?:\s+\d+[wx])(?:,\s*)?)+)["']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5aVwzeRcVRyMBC_l)

Comment: Good answer. I realised JavaScript regex can't repeat capture groups after posting. Really, the solution is "Don't use regex to parse HTML you fools."